# How to prevent words from being split up from line to line

Tags: java, string, printing

Currently, when I print a string onto the command line from a Java program, the text will print out until it hits the edge of the window, then drop down to the new line. Is there a way I can print in such a way so that words aren't cut in half when I drop to the new line? Thanks.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], however simple the question is.

Comment: There is no way to guarantee this, as there is no way to reliably know the width of the console.

Comment: It is not your Java program that is doing that; it is your console. If you cut the full text and paste it into a wider console window, you will see that there is no newline. Depending on the operating system you are using, you might be able to turn off autowrapping on the console.

Comment: The console width is 80 characters

Comment: There are many things you *could* do, including 1) parse your string, and insert a Java `\n` character at the nearest whitespace character before "80", for each "line", 2) Use a screen control library like [JCurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/), 3) etc. etc..  But I suspect these options are probably "overkill" for your particular use case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed your other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939030/).

It sounds like you're coding a text-mode game in Java.  In that case, you should *definitely* look at a "screen control library".  [ncurses](https://www.viget.com/articles/game-programming-in-c-with-the-ncurses-library/) is a standard library for the C/C++ community (among others).

You might be interested in [Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) or [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html) for Java.